# Can I get the ::after state of a table row to position relative to its normal state?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create a gradient bottom border to separate my table rows.

I'm using the ::after state of the table row to create the border and trying to use position: absolute to position it at the bottom of the row. I think the problem is that the table row's ::after state is seeing the table element as the closest parent with a defined position and not the normal state of the table row. I've given the table row position: relative to try to get the ::after state to position relative to the row, but to no avail.

Is there any way I can get the ::after state to position at the bottom of each row and not at the bottom of the whole table?

```css
.beat-store {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.beat-store__song {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
  height: 6rem;
}

.beat-store__song:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 6rem);
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0), #cccccc, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0));
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<table class="beat-store">
  <tr class="beat-store__song">
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__album-art-box">
      <img src="assets/images/photos/me.JPG" alt="album art" class="beat-store__album-art">
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-details">
      <p class="beat-store__song-name">Antarctica</p>
      <p class="beat-store__song-genre">Hip Hop</p>
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-bpm">120</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-time">3:04</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__actions">
      <div class="beat-store__actions-group">
        <img src="assets/icons/favorite--unchecked.svg" alt="favourite" class="favourite-icon">
        <img src="assets/icons/share-dark.svg" alt="share" class="share-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn--add-to-cart">
          <i class="cart-icon"></i>
          <p>Add to Cart</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="beat-store__song">
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__album-art-box">
      <img src="assets/images/photos/me.JPG" alt="album art" class="beat-store__album-art">
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-details">
      <p class="beat-store__song-name">Antarctica</p>
      <p class="beat-store__song-genre">Hip Hop</p>
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-bpm">120</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-time">3:04</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__actions">
      <div class="beat-store__actions-group">
        <img src="assets/icons/favorite--unchecked.svg" alt="favourite" class="favourite-icon">
        <img src="assets/icons/share-dark.svg" alt="share" class="share-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn--add-to-cart">
          <i class="cart-icon"></i>
          <p>Add to Cart</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="beat-store__song">
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__album-art-box">
      <img src="assets/images/photos/me.JPG" alt="album art" class="beat-store__album-art">
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-details">
      <p class="beat-store__song-name">Antarctica</p>
      <p class="beat-store__song-genre">Hip Hop</p>
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-bpm">120</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-time">3:04</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__actions">
      <div class="beat-store__actions-group">
        <img src="assets/icons/favorite--unchecked.svg" alt="favourite" class="favourite-icon">
        <img src="assets/icons/share-dark.svg" alt="share" class="share-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn--add-to-cart">
          <i class="cart-icon"></i>
          <p>Add to Cart</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Any help regarding my issue or advice on tables (I don't work with them often) will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: I moved your code to a snippet and it appears to be working as you expect it. What browser are you using? Also, you may want to consider not using a `table` for this.

Comment: Viewing the snippet, I see what the OP sees: Only 1 gradient divider at the bottom of the table. Chrome version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you what you are looking for. I removed the ::after pseudo-element because I don't believe the method you were using was appropriate for the task. You may need to apply additional styling to `.beat-store__song` to achieve desired results. It's hard to predict when using placeholders for images.

I think what you were missing is that using `::after` is intended to insert some content after the element and any styling specified in the `::after` pseudo-element applies only to the added content. In your case the added content was empty.

```css
.beat-store {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.beat-store__song {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
  height: 6rem;
}

.beat-store__song:not(:last-child) {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0), #cccccc, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom; 
  background-size:calc(100% - 6rem) 1px;
  
}
```

```html
<table class="beat-store">
  <tr class="beat-store__song">
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__album-art-box">
      <img src="assets/images/photos/me.JPG" alt="album art" class="beat-store__album-art">
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-details">
      <p class="beat-store__song-name">Antarctica</p>
      <p class="beat-store__song-genre">Hip Hop</p>
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-bpm">120</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-time">3:04</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__actions">
      <div class="beat-store__actions-group">
        <img src="assets/icons/favorite--unchecked.svg" alt="favourite" class="favourite-icon">
        <img src="assets/icons/share-dark.svg" alt="share" class="share-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn--add-to-cart">
          <i class="cart-icon"></i>
          <p>Add to Cart</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="beat-store__song">
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__album-art-box">
      <img src="assets/images/photos/me.JPG" alt="album art" class="beat-store__album-art">
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-details">
      <p class="beat-store__song-name">Antarctica</p>
      <p class="beat-store__song-genre">Hip Hop</p>
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-bpm">120</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-time">3:04</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__actions">
      <div class="beat-store__actions-group">
        <img src="assets/icons/favorite--unchecked.svg" alt="favourite" class="favourite-icon">
        <img src="assets/icons/share-dark.svg" alt="share" class="share-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn--add-to-cart">
          <i class="cart-icon"></i>
          <p>Add to Cart</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="beat-store__song">
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__album-art-box">
      <img src="assets/images/photos/me.JPG" alt="album art" class="beat-store__album-art">
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-details">
      <p class="beat-store__song-name">Antarctica</p>
      <p class="beat-store__song-genre">Hip Hop</p>
    </td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-bpm">120</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__song-time">3:04</td>
    <td class="beat-store__table-cell beat-store__actions">
      <div class="beat-store__actions-group">
        <img src="assets/icons/favorite--unchecked.svg" alt="favourite" class="favourite-icon">
        <img src="assets/icons/share-dark.svg" alt="share" class="share-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn--add-to-cart">
          <i class="cart-icon"></i>
          <p>Add to Cart</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks, I never thought to use the background properties like that. Much appreciated.